# URL Rewriting : replace "/" with a "#" after the category name

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can anyone help me to rewrite my URL like this using .htaccess :

http://website.com/name-of-category/title-of-the-article 
need to be rewritten to
http://website.com/name-of-category#title-of-the-article

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Something like this ?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(+.)/$ /#$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/$ /$1#$2 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Unfortunately, it doesn't work (nothing happens) with this rule.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file and what URL did you enter? Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: Thank you @anubhava ! The .htaccess file is located in the root directory (/www). Here is the full content : http://bit.ly/TNzWcT

Comment: Is this URL `http://website.com/name-of-category/title-of-the-article` a WP page/post? If yes then use WP's permalink feature to have custom URL scheme.

Comment: Yes, it's a WP post. I already tried to use the permalink feature in Wordpess but it does not work with the hashtag #.

Comment: I have verified without WP that this redirect rule works but I don't know WP well enough to suggest you a way out for WP.

Comment: Thank you so much @anubhava for your help ! I hope someday I will find the solution ;)